# How to link keyof types within an interface

Tags: typescript, keyof

Not sure if this is possible, but it's related to `keyof` which I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around...

I currently have this interface:

```
interface Column<T> {
  header: string;
  field: keyof T;
  format?: (value: any) => string;
}
```

First usage for it is to create something that renders a table, given a list of objects and columns.

```
const rows = [{name: 'Alice', age: 18}, {name: 'Bob', age: 12}];

type Row = typeof rows[0];

const columns: Column<Row>[] = [
  {
    header: 'Name',
    field: 'name',
    format: value => value.toUpperCase(),
  },
  {
    header: 'Age',
    field: 'age',
    format: value => value.toLocaleString(),
  },
];

const renderTable = <T>(rows: T[], columns: Columns<T>[]) { ... }
renderTable(rows, columns);
```

Is there a way to get rid of the `any` type here in the `format` function? To somehow "link" the `keyof T` of `field` with the `value` of `format`? I.e. for the first column `value` should be `string`, and for the second it should be `number`?

---

(I know it would be very easy to just print these out manually, but there's also going to be added some auto-magic stuff to this table which will make use of `field` and `format`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to rely on TypeScript's [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).

This will "map" through every key (`Key in keyof`) in the generic passed (`Row`).

Then for each `Row` key (eg: `name`, `age`, `admin`) we'll assign that an object of the shape you outlined with the properties `header`, `field` and `format`.

However, since we now know we're working with a specific key (eg: `age`) we can use `Key` to reference `age` in this mapped typed and `Row[Key]` to reference the type of `age` (`number`).

Finally, you don't want keys with nested objects, you want only the objects so we can effectively "pluck" those values with `[keyof Row]`, looking up all the values for `"age" | "name" | "admin"` and what is left is the union type of all the possible columns with the `field` and `format` correctly typed.

```js
type Columns<Row> = {
  [Key in keyof Row]: {
    header: string;
    field: Key,
    format?: (value: Row[Key]) => string;
  }
}[keyof Row]

const rows = [{name: 'Alice', age: 18, admin: true }, {name: 'Bob', age: 12, admin: false}];

type Row = typeof rows[0];

const columns: Columns<Row>[] = [
  {
    header: 'Name',
    field: 'name',
    format: value => value.toUpperCase(), // value: string
  },
  {
    header: 'Age',
    field: 'age',
    format: value => value.toLocaleString(), // value: number
  },
 {
    header: 'Admin',
    field: 'admin',
    format: value => value.toString(), // value: boolean
  },
];
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: You beat me by several seconds :P. You should probably add some explanations though